# C# Linq where list in list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an list called mainList. 
Every item in mainList contains another list called detailList.
I want to select items from mainList where a property in detailList evaluates true.

What I hoped would work:

```
var list = mainList.Where(x => x.detailList.Where(y => y.property == true));
```

This does not work, it can not convert detailList to bool.

So my question is how do I select items in the mainList where that item has a valid property inside his detailList.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If all items must be true:

```
var list = mainList.Where(x => x.detailList.All(y => y.property));
```

if atleast one

```
var list = mainList.Where(x => x.detailList.Any(y => y.property));
```

Comment: I'm using .Contains and it is returning duplicate records, any idea why?

Comment: @teapeng because your source contains duplicates.

Comment: Any or All will return all the items if there is at least one match or all matches respectively is there a way only to return a list of items that meet the predicate

Comment: @MakheleSabata thats what the `Where` is for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, any will return True if "any" items in a list meet the condition.

```
var list = mainList.Where(x => x.detailList.Any(y => y.property == true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Been answered, but here's a working example you can run in [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/):

```
void Main()
{
    var foo_list = new List<Foo>();
    foo_list.Add(new Foo(){InnerList = new List<Bar> {
        new Bar{ Pro=true,  Ind =1 },
        new Bar{ Pro=true,  Ind =2 },
        new Bar{ Pro=false, Ind =3 }
    }});
    foo_list.Add(new Foo(){InnerList = new List<Bar> {
        new Bar{ Pro=false, Ind =4 },
        new Bar{ Pro=false, Ind =5 },
        new Bar{ Pro=false, Ind =6 }
    }});

    var l = from x in foo_list
            where x.InnerList.Any(b => b.Pro)
            select x;
    l.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Foo{
    public List<Bar> InnerList {get;set;}
    public Foo() {
        InnerList = new List<Bar>();
    }
}

class Bar {
    public bool Pro { get; set; }
    public int Ind { get; set; }
}
```

The result will hold the first `Foo`, since some of its `Bar`'s have a property `Pro` which is true

[image]